# Python unable to import nested module

Tags: python

I am currently writing a library in Python. I am trying to use a class that I have defined in a module but I am unable to use it in my main.py. Inside Selector and SeasonSelector I have 2 classes defined with the same name of the file. I get the following error:

No name 'Selector' in module 'Selectors'

`main.py`:

```
import pyf1

testSeasonSelector = pyf1.Selectors.SeasonSelector()
testSelector.loadData()
```

`pyf1/__init__.py`:

```
from Selectors.Selector import Selector
from Selectors.SeasonSelector import SeasonSelector
```

Directory

```
├── main.py
└── pyf1
    ├── Selector.pyc
    ├── Selectors
    │   ├── SeasonSelector.py
    │   ├── SeasonSelector.pyc
    │   ├── Selector.py
    │   ├── Selector.pyc
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    └── data
```

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Does `Selectors` have `__init__.py`? Maybe the .pyc there doesn't have the imports. Try add the `__init__.py` inside `Selectors`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile They're classes not functions

Comment: the file names should be lowercase, the class name within the file should be upper case. This is not java. Every language has it's own naming conventions. Though it will work even without respecting naming styles it makes the code much more difficult to read for others.

Comment: Have you tried `from pyf1.Selectors.Selector import Selector`? It might be a problem caused by the location of main.py, which you execute.

Comment: `testSeasonSelector` and `testSelector` are variables, and @gelonida makes a good point about the file names.

Comment: I assume you're now using python3, so I would remove all the .pyc files as they're probably relicts of some python2 execution. Shouldn't cause anly problems though.
You might even remove them from the question (after having removed on your machine), so people who answer don't get distracted py the `*.pyc` files

Comment: if main treats pyf1 as a package because you added a `__init__.py` file, then use `from pyf1.Selectors.Selector import Selector` instead of `from Selectors.Selector import Selector`

or use explicit relative imports with `from .Selectors.Selector import Selector`

in the `pyf/__init__.py` file Explicit relative imports have a leading `.`

With python 2,  add as first python statement `from __future__ import absolute_import` It makes all imports absolute imports by dflt (as with python3) and enables at the same time the relative import syntax with  leading `.`

Answer (score 0):

Your directory should look like this

```
├── main.py
└── pyf1
    ├── selector.pyc
    ├── selectors
    |   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── season_selector.py
    │   ├── season_Selector.pyc
    │   ├── selector.py
    │   ├── selector.pyc
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    └── data
```

Your directory is not a certified package without **init**.py as such you cannot make import statements. I also took the liberty of correcting how you named your modules to fit good python naming convention\practices. With this you should be able to import from your built package without issues

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution.

The issue was I wasn't using the correct syntax. Once I added the missing `__init__()` files I used the import statement `Import .parent_file from ParentClass` Which then allowed me to pass functionality up the chain how I wanted.

Inside the Selectors directory I could then use `from .selector import __Selector` to use in `SeasonSelector`

Furthermore - I hadn't included the PyF1 in my `sys.path`, therefore python wasn't able to scan the directories. This included with the syntax above allowed me to do what I wanted.